# How to develop an Android tool to be used for any text in any app

Tags: android, text, highlight

I'm an Android developer and I'm trying to figure out how to build a tool/app that suggests features to the user when highlighting any text on any other application.

Is that possible? I guess it will be similar to developing the "copy and paste" feature, but I just need to know from where to begin and what do I exactly need to achieve this.

EDITED:

Can I use "The Clipboard Framework" to listen for text selection?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable thing to want to do to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is that possible?

Generally speaking, no, for security reasons.

In this specific case, you could create your own input method editor (a.k.a., soft keyboard), which the user could elect to use, and you could find out when the user selects text in an `EditText`. But writing a good input method editor is *not* simple, and it will have no effect on, say, text highlighted in a Web browser.

> Can I use "The Clipboard Framework" to listen for text selection?

No.

Comment: Thank you! Okay then can I build an extension for the original internet browser and any e-readers to do this?

Comment: @DoaaA.: With respect "the original internet browser", no, you cannot "build an extension" for it. With respect to "any e-readers", you would have to find some and ask them.

Comment: I was just wondering, does this mean I cannot even build my own "copy & paste" tool using the Clipboard? I had a quick look on the code samples provided and I thought it could be re-used.

Comment: @DoaaA.: You can read and write stuff from the clipboard using `ClipboardManager`. However, you asked "Can I use [it] to listen for text selection", and the answer is no -- there is no event that you can listen for from the clipboard to say "somebody has highlighted text somewhere". But, if the user copies text to the clipboard, goes to your app, and clicks a button or something, you can read the text off the clipboard and do something with it.

Answer (score 1):

Mmmmmh, you must do all tutorials and read theory before you start programming anything.
If you don't want to do that, you could start doing things that are already done in tutorials and manuals.

By the way, try to do [THIS](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) tutorial, to learn the basics about save content and manipulating text. Then, [this summary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/package-summary.html) about writing text. And then, you can start thinking about aplications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I use the "The Clipboard Framework"? Like have a broadcast receiver when the user highlights text?

Comment: I will start 1 by the basics, then, use the framework: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/clipboard/copy-paste.html to study hoy it work and learn more. Im studing now that tutoriales, so i cannot help you more today... maybe next week :D