# Android - Can you listen for text-highlight events?

Tags: android, events, highlight

I would like to listen for a text-highlight event in the system not only in my app (i.e at least in chrome).
Is this possible folks and if yes can you please provide a sample implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [How to develop an Android tool to be used for any text in any app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620887/how-to-develop-an-android-tool-to-be-used-for-any-text-in-any-app?rq=1)

> > Is that possible?
>
> Generally speaking, no, for security reasons.
>
> In this specific case, you could create your own input method editor
>   (a.k.a., soft keyboard), which the user could elect to use, and you
>   could find out when the user selects text in an EditText. But writing
>   a good input method editor is not simple, and it will have no effect
>   on, say, text highlighted in a Web browser.
>
> > Can I use "The Clipboard Framework" to listen for text selection?
>
> No.